# How to get project workspace details

Tags: api, asana

To get project names and followers I can use:

https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects?opt_fields=name,followers

However it doesn't let me get the workspace:

https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects?opt_fields=name,workspace

Only the project ids and names are listed. I have tried using `opt_expand` as well. Is it possible to get the workspace when listing projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I work for Asana)

You are correct, this should be possible. It appears to be a bug. We should have this fixed for you later today.

Comment: Thanks! It is working now :) I can't believe how quickly you guys fixed that.